# media query for portrait orientation doesn't seem to work

Tags: css

My media query for portrait orientation doesn't seem to work. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, please?

html:

```
<div class="titleCard" id="first" style="background-color:white"></div>
```

css:

```
html, body { -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;}

#first {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%; max-width: 1920px;
   height: 100%; max-height: 1080px;
   background: url('images/bg.png') no-repeat center; 
   background-size:cover;
   position:relative;
}

.bgwidth { width: 100%; max-width: 1920px; }
.bgheight { height: 100%; max-height: 1080px; }

@media all and (orientation:portrait) { 
    background: url('images/Mobile_Art.jpg') no-repeat center; 
}
```

Comment: Where did you tested this code?

Comment: http://newsinteractive.post-gazette.com/bootstrap2/prohibition/index4.html on a Droid Razr and with Firefox's Tools > Web Developer Extension > Resize > View Responsive Layouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works ([**simplified test**](http://codepen.io/thebabydino/pen/odbig)). It's just that you're not telling it for what element it should change the `background` when the orientation changes.

You probably meant to have something like:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) { 
    #first {
        background: url('images/Mobile_Art.jpg') no-repeat center; 
    }
}
```

instead of:

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) { 
    background: url('images/Mobile_Art.jpg') no-repeat center; 
}
```

Comment: Oh, I feel dumb now! Thank you very much :).